# How do I get DISTINCT columns and COUNT occurrences of sub DISTINCT columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having some difficulty building a file download statistics database and displaying the information how I would like.

Table: customer_statistics

```
| user |  product_id  |  file_download  |  date_accessed        |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| tom  |  1104        |  file_1.pdf     |  2017-05-06 00:00:00  |
| tom  |  1048        |  file_3.pdf     |  2017-05-06 00:00:00  |
| tom  |  1048        |  file_3.pdf     |  2017-05-06 00:00:00  |
| tom  |  1048        |  file_3.pdf     |  2017-05-06 00:00:00  |
| tom  |  1048        |  file_3.pdf     |  2017-05-06 00:00:00  |
| tom  |  1010        |  file_3.pdf     |  2017-05-06 00:00:00  |
| tom  |  1077        |  file_3.pdf     |  2017-05-06 00:00:00  |
| sue  |  1749        |  file_2.pdf     |  2017-05-06 00:00:00  |
| sue  |  1284        |  file_3.pdf     |  2017-05-06 00:00:00  |
| sue  |  1284        |  file_3.pdf     |  2017-05-06 00:00:00  |
| sue  |  1065        |  file_1.pdf     |  2017-05-06 00:00:00  |
| sue  |  1344        |  file_3.pdf     |  2017-05-06 00:00:00  |
| sue  |  2504        |  file_2.pdf     |  2017-05-06 00:00:00  |
```

I need to display the following based on the table above:

> Tom has downloaded `file_3.pdf` from `3` different products but has downloaded `file_3.pdf` from `product_id 1048` 4 times.
>
> Tom has also downloaded `file_1.pdf` from `1` product and only once from that `product_id`
>
> Tom has a total of `7` downloads from `4` different products
>
> Sue has downloaded `file_3.pdf` from `2` different products but has downloaded `file_3.pdf` from `product_id 1284` 2 times.
>
> Sue has also downloaded `file_1.pdf` from `1` product and only once from that `product_id`
>
> Sue has also downloaded `file_2.pdf` from `1` product and only once from that `product_id`
>
> Sue has a total of `6` downloads from `5` different products

What would the best way to do this?

Do I need to restructure my table?

Comment: You want the result to look like *that*?

Comment: @Strawberry - of course not, I just want those values - I spelled it out that way so it's easy to understand.

Comment: Well, can you spell it out differently?

Comment: @Strawberry are you not able to understand what I'm looking?

Comment: Show the results in a tabular format in the question.

Comment: You might need to split it up in to 2 queries. One sounds like a group by user and file_downlaod and the other query sounds like a group by user and product_id? am i on the right track?

Comment: This is just a dump of your requirements, without specifying how the output should look like and any demonstration of own efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following...

```
SELECT user AS user,
       file_download AS file_download,
       product_id AS product_id,
       COUNT( * ) AS CountPerProduct,
       CountOfProducts AS CountOfProducts
FROM customer_statistics
JOIN ( SELECT user AS user,
              file_download AS file_download,
              COUNT( product_id ) AS CountOfProducts
       FROM ( SELECT user AS user,
                     file_download AS file_download,
                     product_id AS product_id
              FROM customer_statistics
              GROUP BY user,
                       file_download,
                       product_id
            ) AS uniqueComboFinder
       GROUP BY user,
                file_download
     ) AS CountOfProductsFinder ON customer_statistics.user = CountOfProductsFinder.user
                               AND customer_statistics.file_download = CountOfProductsFinder.file_download
GROUP BY user,
         file_download,
         product_id,
         CountOfProducts;
```

This statement starts by using the following subquery to form a list of unique combinations of `user`, `file_download` and `product_id`...

```
SELECT user AS user,
       file_download AS file_download,
       product_id AS product_id
FROM customer_statistics
GROUP BY user,
         file_download,
         product_id
```

The results of the above subquery are used in the following subquery to get a count of how many `product_id` values that the `user` has downloaded the `file` from...

```
SELECT user AS user,
       file_download AS file_download,
       COUNT( product_id ) AS CountOfProducts
FROM ( SELECT user AS user,
              file_download AS file_download,
              product_id AS product_id
       FROM customer_statistics
       GROUP BY user,
                file_download,
                product_id
     ) AS uniqueComboFinder
GROUP BY user,
         file_download
```

The resulting dataset is then joined to an instance `customer_statistics` in such a way that the count of `product_id` values for each combination of `user` and `file_download` is effectively appended to every corresponding record in `customer_statistics`.

The dataset resulting from this joining is then grouped by each unique combination of `user`, `file_download` and `product_id` and the count of records belonging to each group (i.e. the count of each time that a `user` has downloaded a particular `file` from that `product_id`) is calculated.

I can't remember if `MySQL` requires `CountOfProducts` to be used by `GROUP BY`.  But, even though each combination of `user`, `file_download` and `product_id` determines what the value of `CountOfProducts` will be, many forms of `SQL` require you to `GROUP BY` each nonaggregated field selected.  As such, and since adding `CountOfProducts` to `GROUP BY` does no harm, I have included `CountOfProducts` in the `GROUP BY` clause.

If one or two more rules can be clarified about their structure, then the sentences displayed can be automatically generated.

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

*Appendix*

To exclude a single user from the set of results, please use the following variation.

```
SELECT user AS user,
       file_download AS file_download,
       product_id AS product_id,
       COUNT( * ) AS CountPerProduct,
       CountOfProducts AS CountOfProducts
FROM customer_statistics
JOIN ( SELECT user AS user,
              file_download AS file_download,
              COUNT( product_id ) AS CountOfProducts
       FROM ( SELECT user AS user,
                     file_download AS file_download,
                     product_id AS product_id
              FROM customer_statistics
              WHERE user <> excludedUser
              GROUP BY user,
                       file_download,
                       product_id
            ) AS uniqueComboFinder
       GROUP BY user,
                file_download
     ) AS CountOfProductsFinder ON customer_statistics.user = CountOfProductsFinder.user
                               AND customer_statistics.file_download = CountOfProductsFinder.file_download
GROUP BY user,
         file_download,
         product_id,
         CountOfProducts;
```

I have used `excludedUser` here, but you can replace that with a constant value (such as `Sam`) or a variable that holds the targetted value.

Please note that I have added the `WHERE user <> excludedUser` clause to the innermost subquery.  Because its parent subquery's results are based entirely on the results of the innermost subquery, the excluded user will not be represented in the parent subquery's reults.  And since the excluded `User` value does not appear in the parent subquery's results, when the main statement's `INNER JOIN` is performed based (in part) on the shared values of `User`, then the targetted `User` will be excluded from the joined dataset as well.

By adding the `WHERE` clause to the innermost subquery, I avoided a small amount of unnecessary processing by the middle and outer levels of the statement, thus making the overall statement slightly more efficient than if the `user` value had been excluded at the middle or outer levels.

Similarly, if more than one `User` needs to be excluded, you can exclude them by explicitly coding their values of `User` into the statement or by joining to a table of exclusionary values.  For the first case use...

```
SELECT user AS user,
       file_download AS file_download,
       product_id AS product_id,
       COUNT( * ) AS CountPerProduct,
       CountOfProducts AS CountOfProducts
FROM customer_statistics
JOIN ( SELECT user AS user,
              file_download AS file_download,
              COUNT( product_id ) AS CountOfProducts
       FROM ( SELECT user AS user,
                     file_download AS file_download,
                     product_id AS product_id
              FROM customer_statistics
              WHERE user NOT IN ( 'Sam', 'I', 'Am' )
              GROUP BY user,
                       file_download,
                       product_id
            ) AS uniqueComboFinder
       GROUP BY user,
                file_download
     ) AS CountOfProductsFinder ON customer_statistics.user = CountOfProductsFinder.user
                               AND customer_statistics.file_download = CountOfProductsFinder.file_download
GROUP BY user,
         file_download,
         product_id,
         CountOfProducts;
```

In the second case use...

```
SELECT user AS user,
       file_download AS file_download,
       product_id AS product_id,
       COUNT( * ) AS CountPerProduct,
       CountOfProducts AS CountOfProducts
FROM customer_statistics
JOIN ( SELECT user AS user,
              file_download AS file_download,
              COUNT( product_id ) AS CountOfProducts
       FROM ( SELECT user AS user,
                     file_download AS file_download,
                     product_id AS product_id
              FROM customer_statistics
              WHERE user NOT IN ( SELECT user
                                  FROM excludedUsers
                                )
              GROUP BY user,
                       file_download,
                       product_id
            ) AS uniqueComboFinder
       GROUP BY user,
                file_download
     ) AS CountOfProductsFinder ON customer_statistics.user = CountOfProductsFinder.user
                               AND customer_statistics.file_download = CountOfProductsFinder.file_download
GROUP BY user,
         file_download,
         product_id,
         CountOfProducts;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you a hint to get you going.

Start with ditching the individual download records in favor of aggregates, like so:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS basic_aggregated_stats
SELECT user, file_id, product_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt 
  FROM customer_statistics
  GROUP BY user, file_id, product_id;
```

This is just one step (which, by the way, could also be used as a subquery in a larger more complicated query). There are more aggregations you can and should do to get the information you need. That's not really "restructuring the table".

In addition to more aggregation you need to consider getting the order right and producing subtotals as well.